# How to reference an android library that is stored in a subfolder of the main android project?(I am using gradle and eclipse)

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-build, gradle-eclipse

I want to store a library project (FB SDK)my main project is depending on in the subfolder of my main project.
Heres what I have done so far:
Copied the FB SDK library project in the libs folder.
Added the following line in build.gradle:
compile project(':libs:facebook')

However my main project does not seem to recognize the SDK calls.

Adding android.library.reference.2=./libs/facebook or even .\libs\facebook to project.properties does not solve the issue.
Any idea what i`m missing?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have declared it in the `settings.gradle` file

```
include ':app', ':libs:facebook'
```